How to align point clouds in Python
So. I have an assignment where I need to find the rotation matrix and the translation vector to be able to transform a point cloud A to align with the point cloud B.
The point clouds have the shape (3000, 3), where each point is a vector of lenght 3
I have this function to center a point cloud around its mean
def center_cloud(cloud):
    center = np.array([np.mean(cloud, axis=0)])

    return center, cloud - center

This function the that returns an array with the closest B point to each A point
def get_correspondence_array(A, B):
    distance_matrix = np.sum((A[:, np.newaxis] - B)**2, axis=2)
    min_dist_idx = np.argmin(distance_matrix, axis=1)

    return min_dist_idx

This one calculates the cross-covariance between each A point and it's corresponding closest B point
def calc_cross_covariance(A, B, corresp):
    covariance = np.zeros((3, 3))

    for i in range(len(corresp)):
        point_a = A[i]
        point_b = B[corresp[i]]

        covariance = np.outer(point_a, point_b) + covariance

    return covariance 

And, finally, I have my ICP function:
def icp(A, B, n_iterations):
    center_of_B, centralized_B = center_cloud(B)

    final_rotation_mat = np.eye(3)
    final_translation_vec = np.array([np.zeros(3)])

    transformed_cloud = A.copy()

    for i in range(n_iterations):
        center_of_A, centralized_A = center_cloud(transformed_cloud)
        correspondences = get_correspondence_array(centralized_A, centralized_B)

        covariance = calc_cross_covariance(centralized_A, centralized_B, correspondences)

        U, S, V_T = np.linalg.svd(covariance)

        rotation_mat = U @ V_T
        final_rotation_mat =  rotation_mat @ final_rotation_mat

        translation_vec = center_of_B - (rotation_mat @ center_of_A.T).T
        final_translation_vec = final_translation_vec + translation_vec

        transformed_cloud = (rotation_mat @ centralized_A.T).T + translation_vec

    # I've also tried to get the translation vector from the original centers of A and B
    # instead of accumulating inside the loop: 
    
    #final_translation_vec = center_of_B - (rotation_mat @ center_of_A.T).T

    return transformed_cloud, final_rotation_mat, final_translation_vec

And then I call the ICP function:
cloud_a = trimesh.load_mesh(f"dataset/000000/000000_points.obj").vertices
cloud_b = trimesh.load_mesh(f"dataset/000001/000001_points.obj").vertices

cloud_a = np.asarray(cloud_a)
cloud_b = np.asarray(cloud_b)

cloud_a_sb = cloud_a[:3000] # the point clouds are bigger than 3000, so I get a subset of the cloud
cloud_b_sb = cloud_b[:3000]

t, rot_mat, translat_vec = icp(cloud_a_sb, cloud_b_sb, 10)

new_position = (rot_mat @ cloud_a_sb.T).T + trans_vec

# I've omitted the declaration of this function because it isn't relevant to my problem
plot_cloud_comparison(new_position, cloud_b_sb) 

The ICP function was supposed to return the rotation matrix and a translation vector that aligns both point clouds, but there is a problem somewhere. I did several tweaks to this code, but I still haven't found where is the problem.
Obs: I can't use any library that already implements ICP, I have to code it myself.
